# jquery change event not registering for dynamcally added select

Tags: jquery, select, dynamic

Hoping someone can help, I've got some noddy jquery to kick off when someone changes a select, its as follows: -

```
$(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        var banana = $(this).attr("id");

        if((banana.indexOf("forms[")>-1)){
            var formID= $(this).val();
            getFormInformation(formID);
        }
    });
});
```

This works fine for all selects that appear on the page when its first loaded, however, I also have some jQuery in there that will dynamically add extra selects to the page with a post, and its not picking it up for those, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to attach the event handlers to the dynamically appended elements. Check answer below.

Comment: When I try this by using the line `$(document).on("change", "select", (function() {` kindly provided by Chris below it doesn't work at all... :/

Comment: Is there any error? IF yes please post it here without hesitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach the event handlers to the dynamically appended elements. Using `jQuery`, the `.on()` method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the `jQuery object`. As of `jQuery 1.7`, the `.on()` method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

This might help you:

```
$(document).on('click','select',function(){
    alert("click");
});
```

Also have a look at the `.on()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$("select").change(function() {
```

To:

```
$(document).on("change", "select", (function() {
```

Comment: Sorry when I do this nothing happens at all, not even for the selects that are there at the start...  It doesn't even call the function, which I checked by just putting an alert("hello world") in there to see if its being picked up... :/

Comment: But, look at this jsFiddle I've just knocked up, it does work... http://jsfiddle.net/cS2qq/

Comment: aha I found the problem, you very kindly gave me the replacement line but there is an erroneous "(" before function which I hadn't spotted which was stopping it working, all now great thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use 'on' instead http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(function() {
  $('body').on('change','select', function() {
        var banana = $(this).attr("id");

        if((banana.indexOf("forms[")>-1)){
            var formID= $(this).val();
            getFormInformation(formID);
        });
});
```

Comment: This didnt work either, but curiously when I view the page source after using my post to add another select its not showing in the page source at all (though I can see its details in firebug etc), should it be showing and could this be the cause?  Could this be whats causing it and if so could I just alter the html that I'm adding so the new dropdowns trigger this change function?  Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Upshot is it didnt work with $('body') but did with $(document), why I don't know...